# Ruby: Install gem in fips mode

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, fips

I have system ruby with version 2.5.3, and I want to run it in fips mode. I want to install gems with fips mode enabled.

In my script, I tried to set

```
OpenSSL.fips_mode = true
```

And then do install gem:

```
gem install [gem-name]
```

But what I can see is, the command to set openssl in fips mode runs in a different shell and fips mode is enabled in that shell only.

And **gem install** is executed in different shell session, so there I don't see the fip's mode enabled.

How can I install/uninstall gems with fips mode enabled?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't FIPS mode an OS-level setting?

Comment: Yeah, but even if it is enabled on OS level, if I try to install gem, and check the fips mode in installer file, I see it is non-fips mode.